# How to disable or fix Class File Editor source not found in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Every time I start debugging, after a line or 2 when I step into the code there's a Class File Editor tab that opens up and I lose my breakpoint and debug in eclipse. It is impossible to debug this way. I've tried attaching a source to the jar but to no avail. Can someone help me? I've read somewhere that I do not need to attach source to be able to debug.

Thanks.

Comment: Well you can't look at the source without having the source, you could try installing a decompiler plugin and see if you can debug through that at all.

Comment: But if I don't want to look at the source code and just continue on with debugging? "Step over" also makes the window pop up.

Comment: That's pretty odd, wouldn't think that would happen.

Answer (score 0):

While debugging you can normally see the source from the project you're debugging in, from projects added to the class path and from libs in the class path that have source code attached. This brings up the queytions: Where do you attach the source? Is this in the same project you're debugging in?

On the other hand is normally sufficient to debug through your own code. That is you either just skip through the code without source attachment or you explicitely set your breakpoints. Why do you need to see the source of classes that do not belong to your project?

Comment: How would I skip through the code or disable the window pop up? Even step over raises it.

Comment: There’s a Step filter page under `Preferences ⇒ Java ⇒ Debug` where you can add classes/packages to skip

Comment: If you didn't change the configuration eclipse will always show the class that contains the method at the top of the stack. Normally you'll see the call stack at the top left of the debug view. Stepping through the method calls will eventually bring you back to known code. Using the step over and step return command will speed things up here. Often (expecially when dealing with callbacks or interception) it's easier to just set another breakpoint and use the continue command instead of stepping all the way through.